# Entry points on different urls possible?

Tags: gwt

I've got a typical gwt project, but am using some url rewriting techniques such that urls entered like:

```
www.mysite.com/johndoe
www.mysite.com/janedoe
```

all get served by my main entrypoint project.jsp file. This works great when deployed.

When I'm running in hosted mode, it's a total bummer because changing the url in the browser breaks the link with the hosted-mode debugging, such that when I make changes to the source in eclipse and refresh, those changes are not immediately shown. I need to recompile the app and relaunch, and we all know how long that takes.

Is there any way to somehow get the hosted-mode environment to recognize that the same webapp is being served on these different urls, and just reconnect the debugging connection?

We basically get:

```
http://localhost:8888/myproject.jsp?gwt.codesvr=192.168.1.2:9997
```

when launching hosted mode, I'd like:

```
http://localhost:8888/johndoe
```

to just reconnect to the debugger, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the URL paramater:

```
?gwt.codesvr=192.168.1.2:9997
```

has to appear in your url for the devmode plugin to "kick in". So why not add a rule which "persists" this param when running in hosted mode?

(`GWT.isScript()`)